# Get URL from Imgur API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, imgur

I am trying to use JavaScript to upload image to imgur by [this example](https://github.com/paulrouget/miniuploader/blob/gh-pages/index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><meta charset="utf8"><title>Yo.</title>
<div>DROP!<button onclick="document.querySelector('input').click()">Or click</button></div>
<input style="visibility: collapse; width: 0px;" type="file" onchange="upload(this.files[0])">
<script>
/* Drag'n drop stuff */
window.ondragover = function(e) {e.preventDefault()}
window.ondrop = function(e) {e.preventDefault(); upload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); }
function upload(file) {

    /* Is the file an image? */
    if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;

    /* It is! */
    document.body.className = "uploading";

    /* Lets build a FormData object*/
    var fd = new FormData(); // I wrote about it: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/
    fd.append("image", file); // Append the file
    fd.append("key", "6528448c258cff474ca9701c5bab6927"); // Get your own key http://api.imgur.com/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create the XHR (Cross-Domain XHR FTW!!!) Thank you sooooo much imgur.com
    xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"); // Boooom!
    xhr.onload = function() {
        // Big win!
        document.querySelector("#link").href = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
        document.body.className = "uploaded";
    }
    // Ok, I don't handle the errors. An exercice for the reader.

    /* And now, we send the formdata */
    xhr.send(fd);
}
</script>

<!-- Bla bla bla stuff ... -->

<style>
body {text-align: center; padding-top: 100px;}
div { border: 10px solid black; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; width: 200px; margin: auto; font-size: 40px; display: inline-block;}
#link, p , div {display: none}
div {display: inline-block;}
.uploading div {display: none}
.uploaded div {display: none}
.uploading p {display: inline}
.uploaded #link {display: inline}
em {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0}
</style>

<p>Uploading...</p>
<a id="link">It's online!!!</a>
```

This example put image url in a link and liked to text "It's online!!!"

Could you help me how to get the URL of image after uploaded? I want display image URL (e,g replace "It's online!!!" with the URL) instead of put it in a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting setting #link's `href` value, set its `innerHTML` value. Or the `innerHTML` value of some other element.

```
document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = 'The url';
```

*Edit:* See http://jsfiddle.net/XVvyJ/1/

Comment: The URL is in JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page but how can I display it? I am poor of Javascript.

Comment: I replaced "document.querySelector("#link").href" with "document.getElementById('link').innerHTML" but it doesn't work.

Comment: What element is `#link`? Could you show me the HTML code? (You can edit your post)

Comment: I edited the code (source: https://github.com/paulrouget/miniuploader/blob/gh-pages/index.html). Please give me some advice. Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/XVvyJ/1/ Just drag and drop some image into it to test. I basically added the line I suggested into your code.

Please mark your post as answered if it has helped you! ;)

Comment: @Raintree when I add my own Client ID, instead of your "6528448c258cff474ca9701c5bab6927", I get an error: 

POST http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json 400 (Bad Request)
upload
window.ondrop
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'links' of undefined 
xhr.onload